# R:Weighted Exponential Function with nls and lm not the same

Tags: r

im struggeling with something. If i estimate an exponential function with lm and using transformation ie.

```
    leastsquares.complete=lm(log(PPPrate)~Highest+Mortrate5Y+Crate+DummieJan+DummieDec,weights=Notional)
b.completebestin= predict.lm(leastsquares.completebestout)
Forecast.completebestin= exp(b.completebestin)
```

I get different result than using a weighted nls

```
form<-as.formula(PPPrate~exp(alfa0+alfa1*Highest+alfa2*Mortrate5Y+alfa3*Crate+alfa4*DummieJan+alfa5*DummieDec))
nlsresultshehe=nls(
  form,
  data=AllDataXX,
  start=list(alfa0=1,alfa1=1,alfa2=1,alfa3=1,alfa4=1,alfa5=1),trace=TRUE,
  weight=Notional,control=nls.control(minFactor=0.0001,maxiter = 5000))
T=summary(nlsresultshehe)$parameters
Forecast=exp(T[1,1]+Highest*T[2,1]+Mortrate5Y*T[3,1]+Crate*T[4,1]+DummieJan*T[5,1]+DummieDec*T[6,1])
```

Does it have something to do with the weighting scheme? im kinda lost here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fitting two different models.

- The `lm` call fits a straight line through the log-transformed response. It's finding the line that minimises the sum of squared residuals on the log scale.
- The `nls` call fits an exponential line without transforming anything. It's finding the line that minimises the sum of squared residuals on the *original* scale.

In general, you're not going to get the same result from both these cases.

Comment: Thanks, that clearifies it. nls seems to overfit more often. Is this often the case?

Comment: Well, `nls` gives you more flexibility, which can be a good or a bad thing. Unless you have some background knowledge of the problem, it's easy to over-interpret random noise and try to fit it as part of the model. However, questions like "what model is better to use?" are really better suited to Cross Validated, which is the statistics/machine learning StackExchange site.